# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Relating to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, jsonparser

I did the same thing on what my professor taught us, but when i try to do it in my own computer (which i did in our school computers) I'm having a error with `AsyncTask` that is related with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, But I'm a little bit beginner in android development using java, Cause I'm using react-native in mobile development.

I have not tried anything else because I'm a little bit noob in java and android studio.
But I've found out that my system and in school have some different specs or version of software.

```
Softare/Tool   |  My_SYSTEM | School_SYSTEM
Android Studio | 3.0+       | 2.1
Java           |  8         | 8
Javac          |  8         | 11
```

Is there a problem with my software or tools that causes me the error

This is the `doInBackground` Method

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args0) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", lname));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_sample1, "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //success
                    String success_res = "Success";
                    Log.d("Success Response", success_res);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Saved!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This is my PHP file. I have double check it on my browser still no error for it

```
<?php
include("connection.php");

$response = array();

if(isset($_POST['lastname'])){
    $last = $_POST['lastname'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tblsample1('lname') VALUES ('$last')");

    if($result){
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "successful";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }else{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "error";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}else{
    $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Please input lastname";
        echo json_encode($response);
}


?>
```

I also included the permission tag on `AndroidManifest` so I could use internet on my android app.

And this is my `logcat` whenever I press the submit button

```
2019-05-27 15:06:25.887 13296-13330/com.example.prjsample1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.prjsample1, PID: 13296
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory;
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146)
        at com.example.prjsample1.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:42)
        at com.example.prjsample1.MainActivity$sample1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:69)
        at com.example.prjsample1.MainActivity$sample1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.<init>(AbstractHttpClient.java:187) 
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.<init>(DefaultHttpClient.java:146) 
        at com.example.prjsample1.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:42) 
        at com.example.prjsample1.MainActivity$sample1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:69) 
        at com.example.prjsample1.MainActivity$sample1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:51) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.prjsample1-87DfVwPm8J-fG1nxPkKpFQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:101)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:75)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:164)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73)
        at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88)
2019-05-27 15:06:25.890 13296-13330/com.example.prjsample1 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I should have a toastmaketest when I press the submit button which it actually did when we do it on the schoool computer

Comment: Your project seems to be missing a library (*Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path: (...)*). Maybe the project on the school computer has it but it isn't on your current machine or the paths are not the same.

Comment: @deHaar idk why, but i copy all the files that our professor give to us.

Comment: @deHaar and load it in our libs folder

Comment: Then you will have to get familiar with the organisation of java and android projects. What files has your professor provided? How do you *copy* them into the android studio (project)? Where exactly do you find something about this library in the files provided by your professor?

Answer (score 0):

The crash says **Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory" on path**.

It means, there is a missing dependency of **slf4j**. Add **slf4j** to the module level `build.gradle` file.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-android
implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-android', version: '1.7.26'
```

**How to add the dependency to the `build.gradle` file.**

1. Open the project tools window (Shortcut: Windows: Alt + 1    or Mac: Command + 1). [You'll see it in the top left corner of the Android Studio.]
2. Expand the `app` folder to find the `build.gradle` file. [There will be multiple `build.gradle` files. Make sure the file is inside the `app` folder alongside `src`, `build` folder and not outside it.]
3. Open the `build.gradle` file and scroll down to find the `dependencies` block. [Looks something like below.]

   ```
   dependencies {
       implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion"
       implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
       implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintVersion"
   ...
       implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-android', version: '1.7.26'
   }
   ```
4. Add the dependency to the block (like above).

Comment: Sorry for my noobness, I dont know how to add this depency. Can you teach me how? Should I copy paste this in the file?

Comment: Yes, you have to copy that line to the said folder. Check the updated answer and let me know if you're still having issues adding the line.